# Is there a way to dispatch actions between two namespaced vuex modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

Is it possible to dispatch an action between namespaced modules?

E.g. I have Vuex modules "gameboard" and "notification". Each are namespaced. I would like to dispatch an action from the gameboard module in the notification module.

I thought I could use the module name in the dispatch action name like this:

```js
// store/modules/gameboard.js
const actions = {
    myaction ({dispatch}) {
        ...
        dispatch('notification/triggerSelfDismissingNotifcation', {...})
    }
}
```

```js
// store/modules/notification.js
const actions = {
    triggerSelfDismissingNotification (context, payload) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I try to do this I get errors that make me think Vuex is trying to dispatch an action within my gameboard module:

> [vuex] unknown local action type: notification/triggerSelfDismissingNotification, global type: gameboard/notification/triggerSelfDismissingNotification

Is there a way of dispatching actions from a given Vuex module to another, or do I need to create some kind of a bridge in the root Vuex instance?

Answer (score 564, accepted):

You just need to specify that you're dispatching from the root context:

```js
// from the gameboard.js vuex module
dispatch('notification/triggerSelfDismissingNotifcation', {...}, {root:true})
```

Now when the dispatch reaches the root it will have the correct namespace path to the notifications module (relative to the root instance).

This is assuming you're setting `namespaced: true` on your Vuex store module.

Comment: This is the only hit on the internet for my search for a solution.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: @PeterRoehlen The same for me. I'just take a view to official docs and this options is not documented.

Comment: To be fair, it is documented here https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html at "Accessing Global Assets in Namespaced Modules". Though it is kind of awkward to take in.

Comment: I love vue, but it seems to me that vuex adds more layers of difficulty rather than make it simpler. Now I know that this is not the purpose of vuex but still, isn't it annoying that I always need to be aware of some conventions like in this example `notification/trigger`, then if i want it to be a little bit more generic I do ``${NOTIF_TYPE_NAME}/${NOTIF_TRIGGER_ACTION}``, still need the slash, or even create a helper function for this, I feel that when I want my App to be more modular I pay a lot more than I get. This is my opinion

Comment: You can use `this.dispatch`. It doesn't need `{root: true}`. This is global.

Comment: No you have to use `{root: true}`. The case you meant is probably dispatching to a child module, which indeed (and obviously) does not need this flag.

Comment: an update for current Vuex is that to call actions from other modules the called action needs to be marked as a global - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#register-global-action-in-namespaced-modules

Comment: If your modules are *not* `namespaced: true`, then you can just do `dispatch('triggerSelfDismissingNotifcation', {...}, {root:true})` — without the module name in the first param.

Answer (score 2):

dispatch('mobuleB/actionB', null, { root: true })