# How to call an action from within another action in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following setup for my actions:

```js
get1: ({commit}) => {
  //things
  this.get2(); //this is my question!
},
get2: ({commit}) => {
  //things
},
```

I want to be able to call one action from within another, so in this example I want to be able to call `get2()` from within `get1()`. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 444, accepted):

You have access to the `dispatch` method in the object passed in the first parameter:

```js
get1: ({ commit, dispatch }) => {
  dispatch('get2');
},
```

This is covered in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions).

Comment: Is there a way to do something once an action is complete? Basically use this with a `then()`?

Comment: Yep, it's fully covered in the documentation page I linked

Comment: How can I dispatch an action from another store? e.g. in store A I want to do `dispatch('B/someaction')`

Comment: @Guus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984132/is-there-a-way-to-dispatch-actions-between-two-namespaced-vuex-modules

Answer (score 19):

You can access the dispatch method through the first argument (context):

```js
export const actions = {
  get({ commit, dispatch }) {
    dispatch('action2')
  }
}
```

However, if you use namespaced you need to specify an option:

```js
export const actions = {
  get({ commit, dispatch }) {
    dispatch('action2', {}, { root: true })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

for actions that does not require payload

```js
actions: {
    BEFORE: async (context, payload) => {
    },
    AFTER: async (context, payload) => {
        await context.dispatch('BEFORE');
    }
}
```

for actions that does require **payload**

```js
actions: {
    BEFORE: async (context, payload) => {
    },
    AFTER: async (context, payload) => {
        var payload = {}//prepare payload
        await context.dispatch('BEFORE', payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

we can pass parameters also while dispatching.

```js
dispatch('fetchContacts', user.uid);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
export actions = {
  GET_DATA (context) {
     // do stuff
     context.dispatch('GET_MORE_DATA');
  },

  GET_MORE_DATA (context) {
    // do more stuff
  }
}
```