# Vuex: Best Way To Handle actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am developing a CRUD application to show `user-list`. As an admin, the user list is shown with `edit` & `delete` icons. Once the user is deleted by dispatching `deleteUser` action, the `user-list` should be re-fetched to reflect updated list of users.

```
actions: {
    fetchUsers(context) {
        axios.get("/get/user").then(function(response) {
            context.commit("SET_USERS", response.data);
        });
    },
    deleteUser(context,payload) {
         axios.delete("/delete/user",).then(function(response) {
           if(response.status == 200) {
               //Refresh the user list.
               //HOW TO call "fetchUsers" from here.?
           }
        })
    }
}
```

So I need to call `fetchUsers` action after `delete` user successful.

What is the best way to achieve this? Copying the code would help but it's against DRY principle. `Delete` is an example but there could be several actions like `edit` which would need to call `fetchUsers` again.

Kindly provide inputs.

Regards
Robin.

Comment: Mutations are synchronous, so first you would have to move these methods to `actions`

Comment: @dziraf : I apologize for my wrong question. Yes, this all belongs to actions. So is it possible to re-use actions from another action?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a critical feature of Vuex which is [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html). If you need to perform an async operation regarding a mutation, the async operations should be performed from an action. Within the action, you'll be able to perform other actions, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848974/call-an-action-from-within-another-action) shows.

Comment: Extremely sorry guys, my mistake, I was wrong in mentioning the problem.  It's an action that I need to call repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dispatch()` of the `context` object like this

```
deleteUser(context,payload) {
     axios.delete("/delete/user",).then(function(response) {
       if(response.status == 200) {
           // payload is optional and used if you want to send specific datas to your fetchUsers method
           context.dispatch('fetchUsers', payload)
       }
    })
}
```

cf: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit and https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions