# How can I break my Vuex actions into multiple files and still use `dispatch`?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have broken my actions into multiple files to make my project more maintainable and extensible. Trying to `dispatch` from one action to another, however, is not working.

My file tree looks like this:

```
store.js
actions
  |--actions.js
  |--createShape.js
  |--addShape.js
```

My store.js looks like:

```
import actions from './actions/actions'

const PlaypadStore = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    localState: ''
  },
  actions: {
   ...actions,
  },
}
```

My `actions.js` folder has the following:

```
import CREATE_SHAPE from './createShape';
import ADD_SHAPE from './addShape';

export default {
  CREATE_SHAPE,
  ADD_SHAPE,
}
```

The problem is trying to dispatch `ADD_SHAPE` from `CREATE_SHAPE`. My createShape.js looks like the following:

```
const CREATE_SHAPE = ({ state, dispatch }) => {
  return dispatch('ADD_SHAPE')
}

export default CREATE_SHAPE;
```

But it returns me this:

```
[vuex] unknown local action type
```

The question is this: how can I break my actions into multiple files, but still be able to `dispatch` actions from one to another?

Comment: Can you add in the details how you dispatch these actions as well?

Comment: I might `dispatch` these actions from a component using something like `...mapActions(['myModuleName', 'CREATE_SHAPE')`   for example.

Answer (score 4):

if you use 'export default...' in your action-files and import your files in the store like that:

```
import actions_one from './actions_one';
import actions_two from './actions_two';
```

you can then use the spread operator to make it like you're importing one object:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  actions: {
    ...actions_one,
    ...actions_two
  },
...
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to let Vuex know that `actions.js`, `createShape.js`and `addShape.js`are "modules" of your store for this to work.
You can read more about it in the [Vuex Modules documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html).

Basically you need an `index.js` file declaring the modules at the root of your store. That should look like this:

```js
import actions from "./actions";
import createShape from "./createShape";
import addShape from "./addShape";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    actions,
    createShape,
    addShape
  }
});
```

At this point your dispatch call should work, **UNLESS** it comes from another vuex store module, in that case just specify "root = true" as they pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984132/is-there-a-way-to-dispatch-actions-between-two-namespaced-vuex-modules).

Comment: I want `createShape` and `addShape` to be imported in `actions`.

Comment: If they are two vuex store modules already you should call dispatch with the "root=true" option. There should be no need to import an action A from module A into module B. If this is your need and not to dispatch that action A, maybe that action A should belong to module B.

Comment: Importing from one module into another isn't what I'm trying to. They are both contained within the same module.

Comment: Does it work if you dispatch with the "root=true"? That is in your createShape.js you use: `return dispatch('ADD_SHAPE' ,  {root:true})`